# Django trying to update a specific item that has an id but then also edit other items if need be

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I can't figure out why it won't update/edit an item and then add it back to list with the edits. If someone can help me out thanks! If I find my answer before I get a response I will post it. I posted my `views.py`, `urls.py` and the html for the edit page `confirm_edit.html` just so you can see all of what I am dealing with. thanks for the help!

```js
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from .models import Course

def index(request):
    context = {
        'course' : Course.objects.all()

    }
    return render(request, 'chp1/index.html', context)

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Course.objects.create(SLA_TYPE_CD=request.POST['Name'],
        SLA_TS=request.POST['description'], ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TS=request.POST['description'],
        TICKET_NUM=request.POST['description'], NOTE_TXT=request.POST['description'])
    return redirect('/')

def edit(request, id):
    course_to_edit = Course.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'chp1/confirm_edit.html', {'course' : course_to_edit})

def update(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        course_to_edit.update(SLA_TYPE_CD=request.POST['Name'],
        SLA_TS=request.POST['description'], ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TS=request.POST['description'],
        TICKET_NUM=request.POST['description'], NOTE_TXT=request.POST['description'])
        return redirect('/')

def destroy(request, id):
    course_to_delete = Course.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'chp1/confirm_delete.html', {'course' : course_to_delete})

    course_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

```css
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^create$', views.create),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/destroy$', views.destroy),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit$', views.edit),
]
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Edit SLA_VARIANCE_NOTE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'chp1/css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="addcourse">
    <h2>Are you sure you want to edit the following post?</h2>
    <form action="/{{ course.id }}/edit" method='post'>
      SLA_TYPE_CD: <input type="text" name="Name" value=""> <br>
      SLA_TS: <textarea name="description" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea> <br>
      ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TS: <textarea name="description" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea> <br>
      TICKET_NUM: <textarea name="description" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea> <br>
      NOTE_TXT: <textarea name="description" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea><br>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <a href="/"><button>Back</button></a>
      <input name="edit" type="submit" value="update">

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a few hints: use `{% url your_route_name %}` in the template for defining `action` of form instead of creating the url manually there. `course_to_edit` in `update()` is not declared anywhere, that wont work. Also what exactly happens when it "does not update/edit"? Post some console output and/or error message.

Comment: in your update view you seem to be missing a `course_to_edit = Course.objects.get(id=id)` line